# Framing query_string in Elastic Search with OR and AND Condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query in Elastic Search.

```
(name:anj* OR curriculum:Ba*) AND (syllabus:IEB)
```

I wanted to convert the same as post body for an elastic search.

I wanted to use query_string to achieve the same. Can anyone please hlp me on this.

I tried the below query and it did not work.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": [
      {
        "fields": [
          "brand_name",
          "product_type"
        ],
        "query": "*HALO*",
        "analyze_wildcard": true
      },
      {
        "fields": [
          "tcin"
        ],
        "query": "10038470"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as shoving your current query inside a `query_string` query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(name:anj* OR curriculum:Ba*) AND (syllabus:IEB)"
    }
  }
}
```